# Shiny Update Input Selector issues

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to use the updateSelectInut in Shiny Dashboard to no avail. I have tried multiple methods but am not able to get the selectInput's to update. Data has a VG and AG columns with several factors each. What I want to do is when I select a VG, then this updates with only the AG values that exist for that VG file:

```
VG  AG
A    1
A    2
B    1
B    3
```

Such that if VG is selected then the AG options will be 1,3.

Code is as follows:

```
UI<-...

column(3,selectInput("VG.ETD", label = h4("VG"),choices = levels(data$VG),selected ="Y1")),
column(3,selectInput("AC.ETD", label = h4("AC"),choices = levels(data$AC), selected ="X1")),

Server<-function(input, output,session){...

df_b <- reactive({filter(data, VG== input$VG.ETD)})
observe({updateSelectInput(session, 'AC.ETD', choices=levels(droplevels(df_b()$AC)))})
```

Comment: in your data there is no `data$AC` variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
#rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)

VG <- c("A","A","B","B")
AG <- c(1,2,1,3)
data <- data.frame(VG, AG)

ui <- fluidPage(
  column(3,selectInput("VG", label = h4("VG.ETD"),choices = levels(data$VG),selected ="Y1")),
  column(3,selectInput("AG", label = h4("AG.ETD"),choices = unique(data$AG),selected ="X1"))
)

server<-function(input,output,session){

  observeEvent(input$VG,{
    updateSelectInput(session, 'AG', choices = unique(data$AG[data$VG %in% input$VG]))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```